# ORA-29285 error While exporting data from oracle database to CSV file using procedure

Tags: oracle, csv, stored-procedures

I have a problem here while exporting data from oracle database to CSV file using a procedure. While exporting data, sometimes the CSV file is getting truncated and the error it shows is "**ORA-29285 - File write error**". The problem here is the file is getting truncated not all the times but randomly.

**Edit** : Below is the chunk of code I used in my procedure

```
conn := utl_file.fopen('sample_directory','output.csv','W',4096);
for i in (select * from per_data)
loop
utl_file.put_line(conn,i.name||','||i.sub||','||to_char(i.start_date,'dd-mon-yy')||','||to_char(i.expire_date,'dd-mon-yy')||','||i.loc||CHR(13));
end loop;
utl_file.fclose(conn);`
```

I am pulling my hair to trace out the reason. Can someone help me out ?

Comment: Showing your procedure code might help. What debugging have you done? What is the length of the data you're trying to write when it fails?

Comment: Please do *not* paste external links to code, and do *not* post  images of your code - [edit] your question and paste the code as text instead.

Comment: @Alex Do the file size matter in this case ? I'm writing thousands of records to the output.

Comment: Yes, if it exceeds 32k, but you said it sometimes works and sometimes errors with the same script - did you mean exactly the same, or with different amounts of data?

Answer (score 2):

One way to get this error is to open the file with a certain maximum line size - [possibly the default 1024](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_file.htm#ARPLS70919) - and then try to write a single line to that file which is longer than that.

In your case you don't seem to be doing that, as you open it with 4096 and your lines are all (apparently) shorter than that.

So you may be hitting [the 32k limitation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_file.htm#ARPLS70942):

> The maximum size of the buffer parameter is 32767 bytes unless you specify a smaller size in FOPEN. If unspecified, Oracle supplies a default value of 1024. **The sum of all sequential PUT calls cannot exceed 32767 without intermediate buffer flushes.**

You don't seem to be doing any flushing. You could change your `put_line` call to auto-flush:

```
utl_file.put_line(conn,
  i.name||','||i.sub||','||to_char(i.start_date,'dd-mon-yy')
    ||','||to_char(i.expire_date,'dd-mon-yy')||','||i.loc||CHR(13),
  true);
```

or keep a counter in your loop and [manually flush](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_file.htm#ARPLS70913) every 100 lines (or whatever number works and is efficient for you).

[As noted in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21645/u_file.htm#TTPLP71575):

> If there is buffered data yet to be written when FCLOSE runs, you may receive WRITE_ERROR when closing a file.

You aren't flushing before you close, so adding an explicit flush - even if you have autoflush set to true - might also help avoid this, at least if the exception is being thrown by the `fclose()` call rather than by `put_line()`:

```
...
end loop;
utl_file.fflush(conn);
utl_file.fclose(conn);
```

Comment: `utl_file.fopen(sample_directory,output.csv,'W',4096);` I think I'm using line size which is greater than what I write to a file. My output is : **Nick,F1333,19-JAN-13,19-JAN-99,IN**. If I run the same script again, the output I get is perfectly fine.

Comment: Are you adding new line characters to the output - and carriage returns if your OS expects those? How many records are you writing out? It's odd if exactly the same output works intermittently. Please add the procedure code to the question so we don't have to guess what you are doing.

Comment: Yes ! I'm adding carriage return to the output. The output contain thousands of records (specifically 80k+). Does it depends on the number of records I'm writing to the output ? And it's really odd and I don't know why did I get the correct output when I run it again. This is a frequent problem.

Comment: Is the data in `per_data` changing between runs?

Comment: I used the same data without any change while running the script again.

Comment: I didn't think it did any automatic flushing without being told to, but perhaps that's O/S dependent (or I'm just wrong) and the intermittent errors are from the timing of background flushing. Does adding explicit flushing prevent the errors?

Comment: I'll try adding explicit flushing. But the correct output file size is around 5KB which is less than what buffer can store. So it should work in the first case also without any flushing, is my understanding correct ?

Comment: I've added explicit flushing to my code as suggested. I didn't know if it worked, the file didn't get truncated for some days and now I'm facing the same problem. Is the flushing O/S dependent thought I explicitly written flush in the code ? I'm confused.

Comment: @learner1 - which mechanism did you use, the autoflush argument to `put_line` or manually flushing occasionally? Has anything else changed from the time it seemed to be working to now it isn't again? (Are you sure your modified code is still running, and hasn't been replaced with someone else's modification of the original, say?)

Comment: I have used auto-flush argument in `put_line`. I'm sure the code is not changed from the time it seemed to be working till now.

Comment: @learner1 - can you add manual flushes; at least a `fflush` before the `fclose`? Does the error stack show the exception coming from the `put_line` or from the `fclose`?

Comment: The error stack is showing `ORA-29285 - File write error` and I believe that it is a `put_line` exception. I'll try adding manual flush and see the result.

Comment: The error stack also tells you the line number; you don't need to believe, just see which line in your procedure it reports. (Unless you're catching the exception, of course, but even then you can use the utility functions to print the original stack).

Comment: I've added a manual flush outside the loop and also traced the line of error. Below is the code amended.
    `end loop;  
    utl_file.fflush(conn);  
    utl_file.fclose(conn);`  

I could notice the error is due to `utl_file.fflush(conn);`. What do that mean ?

Comment: Do `put_line()` add a newline character automatically to the output ? If so when I open my csv file by double clicking (windows OS), will I be able to see my every record in new line ?